# Image upload not working for "AUTHENTICATED USER"

Tags: wysiwyg, media

[Media module](https://drupal.org/project/media) is awesome! But I can not understand why AUTHENTICATED USERS are unable to Upload images from CKEditor( http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor ) module.

I have set permission: `Import media files from the local filesystem` for the AUTHENTICATED USER, but still the uploader doesn't seem to work, except for the admin!

Here is a screenshot showing the Media Module inline uploader works with CKEditor while logged in as Admin:

[image]

Here is a another screenshot showing the Media Module inline uploader do not working with CKEditor while logged in as AUTHENTICATED USER:

[image]

Please give me ideas to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not** give your authenticated users the *Import media files from the local filesystem* permission. It's actually different functionality that could open you up to security risk.

Looking at [media_media_browser_plugin_info()](http://drupalcode.org/project/media.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/media.media.inc#l8), we can see that in order to use the upload plugin, the user has to either have the *Edit media* or the *Administer media* permission. Likely you'll want to assign the former.

I'll file an issue to correct that the import permission is misleading, and improve the description of the *Edit media* permission to be clear this is necessary to upload files in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, for giving me great idea, waiting for the update.. so now what i should do with this issue?

Comment: I told you exactly in my answer what permission you actually need to assign to your authenticated user role: *Edit media*

Comment: many many thanks, is there any way to hide the "Library " tab for AUTHENTICATED USER?